# VirtualBox NAT Network gateway IP

Tags: virtualbox

I've set up a NAT Network in Virtualbox at 10.0.5.0/24 and provided my own DHCP server at 10.0.5.15, it's serving up requests fine and the VMs on that network find each other, but they can't get out.

When using a NAT Network with your own DHCP server, what gateway should you specify? I've tried 10.0.5.1 and 10.0.5.2 with no success.

Comment: specify the same gateway used by your host. there should already be a route between the NAT and the hosts LAN network, so just point the VMs to use the same gateway as the host.

Comment: The correct gateway is the IP address of the host on the 10.0.5.0/24 subnet. Is it possible it is 10.0.5.254? You can find it with ipconfig/ifconfig (Windows OS, *Nix OS, respectively). VirtualBox should have taken everything else into account.